# SilverStripe 4 - large asset downloads exhausts memory_limit in HTTPStreamResponse.php

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a client who has some large (1GB+) private assets in SilverStripe 4. It seems these files are stored in memory while they are streamed/downloaded via HTTPStreamResponse.php. This causes Allowed memory size exhausted errors unless I up the php memory_limit to 1024M.

Is there an alternative to this? The server has only 2GB of RAM so currently only 1 download could stream at a time...